# Getting the gradients of multiple outputs in TensorFlow and not their addition

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gradient

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients), if I have multiple outputs say `y1, y2.. yn`, `tf.gradients` returns `d(y1 + y2 + ... yn)/dx`. But is there a way to get the individual gradients `dy1/dx, dy2/dx, ... dyn/dx` in one go without iterating through each output? Trying to be more precise, if I have 10 inputs, and 5 output nodes, is there a way to get the `10 x 5` array, with each column representing the gradient with respect to the corresponding output node, at once?

Comment: Here's an example https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4897#issuecomment-290997283

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about tf.gradients, but you can do it in eager as well as graph mode in TF 2.0 by calling the "jacobian" method of the tf.GradientTape object. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#jacobian) for examples.